# Write a dax query for calculate the AST and RC values for John Doe and Peter Jones based on the criteria you specified. Find AST 80% and RC 20%

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have only 3 columns Name, city and value,Write a dax query for power bi query will calculate the AST and RC values for John Doe and Peter Jones based on the criteria you specified. The AST value will be 80% of the value for John Doe and 70% of the value for Peter Jones. The RC value will be the remaining 20% of the value for John Doe and 30% of the value for Peter Jones. If possible create only one column where AST AND RC text present for creating a filter when I select AST it will show me AST value from value column.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Show us what you have tried and where you need help. This question feels like test/exam question.

Answer (score 0):

NewColumn =

VAR BaseValue = YourTable[Value]

VAR ASTPercentage =
SWITCH(
YourTable[Name],
"John Doe", 0.8,
"Peter Jones", 0.7,
0
)

VAR RCPercentage = 1 - ASTPercentage

VAR Result =
IF(
ASTPercentage > 0,
"AST",
IF(
RCPercentage > 0,
"RC",
BLANK()
)
)
& " - " & BaseValue * SWITCH(YourTable[Name], "John Doe", ASTPercentage, "Peter Jones", RCPercentage, 0)

RETURN

Result